# How to design a variable bit (m bit) counter using VHDL or Verilog?

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I tried different ways to design a variable bit counter (any counter like ring or Johnson) using VHDL, but all was in vain.

Can anyone help me to overcome this?

Comment: Welcom to StackOverflow, Rahul R. You're supposed to post your code here along with your question.

Comment: I have provided an answer (hopefully useful) but next time please post what you have tried and where you are stuck with it. The [About Page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) is useful for new users, especially 'Get answers to practical, detailed questions' section. For more detail check out [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Otherwise you risk getting your question closed.

Answer (score 1):

In VHDL:

You need to describe the pins of your counter first:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counter
port (
  clk    : in std_ulogic;
  resetn : in std_ulogic;
  count  : out unsigned
);
```

then describe how it behaves:

```
architecture behaviour of counter is

begin
  process(clk) -- run this process whenever CLK changes
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then -- only on the rising edges, run the code
      if reset = '1' then    
        count <= (others => '0'); -- set count to all bits 0
      else
        count <= count + 1; -- you'll need VHDL-2008 switched on to do this as it is reading an output signal
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

When you make use of this counter, the count signal will inherit the right number of bits fromt he signal that is attached to it at the higher level.

Comment: This also works perfectly without VHDL-2008; just make `count` a buffer port.

Answer (score 0):

A Johnson counter [as per the wikipedia schematic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_counter) is just a shift register with the next LSB being the Inverted MSB.

```
module johnson_counter #(
  parameter WIDTH = 4
) (
  input                  clk,
  input                  rst_n,
  output reg [WIDTH-1:0] state
);
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    state <= {WIDTH{1'b0}}; //Replication to extend 1'b0
  end
  else begin
    //Shift Left 1, bit LSB becomes inverted MSB
    state <= {state[WIDTH-2:0], ~state[WIDTH-1]}; //Concatination
  end
endmodule
```